# Put yaml (as data) into a config map

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

Is there a way to store yaml data in a config map?

In my `values.yaml` I have something like the below

```
config:
  filters:
    - kind: Pod
      apiVersion: v1
...
```

In my config map, I'm currently doing

```
...
data:
  config.yaml: |-
    {{ .Values.config }}
```

But in the resulting `configmap` the data is "inlined" and formatted as this

```
...
data:
  config.yaml: >-
    map[filters:[map[apiVersion:v1...
```

Which isn't `yaml` and therefore can't be parsed by the app reading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say  you have a `demo-chart`:

```
.
└── demo
    ├── charts
    ├── Chart.yaml
    ├── templates
    │   ├── configmap.yaml
    │   ├── _helpers.tpl
    │   └── NOTES.txt
    └── values.yaml
```

**values.yaml:**

```yaml
config:
  filters:
    - kind: Pod
      apiVersion: v1
```

**configmap.yaml:**

```yaml
{{- if .Values.config }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-name
data:
  config.yml: |- {{- toYaml .Values.config | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

**Explanation:** `toYaml` parse the data loaded from the values.yaml into YAML and `nindent` put 4 spaces in front of every line.

**Check:**

```sh
$ helm template demo
---
# Source: demo/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-name
data:
  config.yml: |-
    filters:
    - apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `.Files.Get` (see [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)): you can store your YAML file (or basically any other text file) right outside the `template` directory, and import the raw content into the configmap (just remember to `| indent`).

The additional benefit of having the text in a separate file is that your text editor can recognize the language (yaml, python, bash,...) and you can leverage the full support of your development tools, which is handy when the complexity of the chart grows.

For example, given your chart structure with the `raw-files` directory:

```
mychart
   ├─ raw-files       <<<
   │  ├─ example.yaml <<<
   │  └─ script.sh    <<<
   ├─ templates
   │  ├─ configmap.yaml
   │  └─ ...
   ├─ Chart.yaml
   └─ values.yaml
```

you can import the content of `example.yaml` as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-name
data:
  config.yml: |-
{{ .Files.Get "raw-files/example.yaml" | indent 4 }}  # update the indentation according to your style
```

```yaml
$ helm template mychart
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo-name
data:
  config.yml: |-
    filters:
      - kind: Pod
        apiVersion: v1
```

Answer (score -3):

It is more of the guess than the answer, but have you tried:

```
data:
  config.yaml: |-
    config:
      filters:
        - kind: Pod
          apiVersion: v1
```

There is a difference between `>-` and `|-` in a yaml.